# Unity android facebook SDK won't login when facebook app is installed?

Tags: android, facebook, authentication, unity-game-engine

I have read through some articles about this problem , but I didn't understand the answer , can someone please say how to fix this? , thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please provide more detailed description of your problem including your code and errors if such appear.

Comment: ok , Why when I use the facebook interactive console(default test project and code) does facebook only login when the facebook app Isn't installed on the android device?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Facebook Unity SDK on Android - Login fails when FB App installed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19051361/facebook-unity-sdk-on-android-login-fails-when-fb-app-installed)

Comment: ok , could you please link me to that answer and also explain alittle bit , as I have been stuck on this problem for a few days now , thankyou for fast reply =).

Comment: I don't feel like an experienced with android development. I'd suggest contacting user who provided answer in mentioned question and ask for further explanation.

Comment: how do I do that? I couldn't comment on the post I found , so I left an answer which got removed and I can't find any private message user button?

Comment: It seems other person had [similar issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21251565/facebook-android-sdk-4-2-4-cant-log-in-and-islogged-returns-false-with-unity-4-3) and can be contacted [here](http://iamsidv.wordpress.com/about/). I'm sorry I can't help any more.

Answer (score 0):

I just answered this on another post. Basically whats wrong is that facebook is not actually using the android debug.keystore instead its using the keystore you generated in the Project Settings directory. See the link below or check out the sdk fix I made that shows you the actual key hash it's using in unity. Cheers!

[Previous post with more info](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23808657/3660026)

[Facebook Unity 6.1 SDK Fix](https://github.com/Kabe0/Facebook-Unity-Fix)